# Bulk change user passwords who registered after specific date

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been handed a task where we need to update the password for all users who registered after a specific date.  So far I have found that using `wp_insert_user` and passing an `$id` variable will update a user, so I plan to use this to update the password fields.  I also found that I can probably use `get_users` to get all users and pass the `$user->ID` to the `wp_insert_user` function.

**My Question:** How can I check if the user registered after a certain date like 04-08-2016?  So this function should only change the passwords for users who registered after that date.

Here is the code I plan to add to my functions file and run once to update the appropriate users:

```
//New password
$new_password = 'ABC123';

//Get all users
$users = get_users( 'blog_id=1' );

//Loop through each user and update
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    //Assign the user->ID
    $id = $user->ID;

    $userdata = array(
        'id'    => $id, //Passing an ID will update user with fields
        'user_pass'   =>  $new_password
    );

    //Update the user - Add condition to check $user->user_registered and compare to April 08, 2016
    $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
}
```

I can see [here in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) that I have access to `user_registered`, I guess Im trying to think of how to compare the date and execute the `wp_insert_user` function if the `user_registered` is after my date April 8th 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all users registered after a date by using the `get_users()` method with the `date_query` argument:

```
<?php $args = array(
  'date_query'   => array()
); 
get_users( $args ); ?>
```

The `date_query` can be used as a [WP Date Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_date_query/) object or by passing in an array

```
$args = array(
  'date_query'   => array(
    'column' => 'user_registered',
    'after' => array(
      'year'  => 2016,
      'month' => 1,
      'day'   => 1
    ),
  )
);
```

?>

After setting the args, you can run `get_users($args)` and it will return an array of [WP User](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) Objects for each user that was registered after that date.

More information on `get_users` can be found in the [WordPress manual](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)

Comment: Awesome, works great! Thanks for the tip, I did not even realize there was a date query.